# JavascriptExecutor in Selenium Webdriver Java

Tags: java, selenium

Just wanted to ask a simple question.
I'm learning a bit about testing and once again I have a little problem.

In my code I want to call a method that will use JavascriptExecutor.

I write:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver
```

And after that I use it in method:

```
public void clickSearch()
{ js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", sOmEtHiNg);}
```

But then, when I start my code I get : `Null Pointer Exception`.

But... when I simply use JavascriptExecutor in my method
For example:

```
public void clickSearch()
{ ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()",eight); }
```

Then everything is ok and I get no errors.

Someone could please tell me where I make a mistake that causes Null Pointer Exception ?

Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void clickSearch()
{ js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", sOmEtHiNg);}
```

It looks like `js` could be null here, which would throw the exception. We need to ensure `js` is inside the scope for your `clickSearch()` method. Could you try this instead:

```
public void clickSearch()
{
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver 
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", sOmEtHiNg);
}
```

Or possibly:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
clickSearch(js);

public void clickSearch(JavascriptExecutor js)
{
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", sOmEtHiNg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void clickSearch()
{
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver 
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", sOmEtHiNg);
}
```

This one works.
Second one can not be used becouse of the different classes.
I write it on one and run on another :-)
Thanks a lot again :-)